# Unable to execute 'thrift' command after 'gem install thrift'

Tags: ruby, thrift

I'm trying to try some thrift development on the Mac but after 'gem install thrift' is successfully run and thrift is listed in 'gem list', executing 'thrift' gives me a command not found error.  I'm running rvm and have tried several versions of ruby from ruby-1.8.7-p358 to ruby-2.0.0-p195.  I'm looking for troubleshooting tips or any other suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at http://rubydoc.info/gems/thrift/0.9.0/frames includes the caveat

> This library provides the client and server implementations of thrift. It does not provide the compiler for the .thrift files. To compile .thrift files into language-specific implementations, please download the full thrift software package.

This would indicate to me that there might not be any command line feature installed as part of this gem.  Have you tried to invoke the library from Ruby?

Comment: D'oh!  That makes perfect sense.  I tried to RTFM but couldn't find much literature, was looking in the wrong place.  Thanks very much.